# Заменяются символы при формировании innerHTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Разрабатываю сайт на ASP MVC4. Во вьюшке есть код, генерирующий выделенный стилем текст

```
function coloringSames(text, sames) {
    var result = text;
    for (var i = sames.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result = text.substring(0, sames[i].StartPos) +
            '</span><span class="same-color">' +
            text.substring(sames[i].StartPos, sames[i].EndPos + 1) +
            '</span><span>' +
            text.substring(sames[i].EndPos + 1, text.length - 1);
    }
    return '<span>' + result + '</span>';
}
```

Функции возвращает нормальную разметку, но при вставке на страницу

```
document.getElementById("textWork").innerHTML = coloringSames(document.getElementById("text").innerText, webPage.SameSubstringsOriginal);
```

Символы '<' и '>' заменяются на &lt и &lg
Почему так происходит и как решить эту проблему?

Comment: innerText делает эту трансформацию. Попробуйте использовать innerHTML вместо него.

Comment: Оказывается все дело в textarea, которому я присваиваю innerHTML. он преобразовывает символы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте класс [MvcHtmlString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring(v=vs.118).aspx), специально предназначенный для решения этой задачи.